# Using .filter to show DB entries created (today) in Django

Tags: python, django, django-orm

My form allows users to create entries into the database and is timestamped with:

```
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

This creates entries like: 2015-02-20 03:10:00

How can I use the .filter to search just the day part of the timestamp? I have so far:

```
for running in viewteam.daily_risk_set.all().filter(team = 4713).filter(created = today).order_by('-created')[:1]:
    // do something
```

I am looking to show just the last entry for team 4713 but I do not know how to work with the dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Date objects are treated as the `DATE 00:00:00` datetime in querysets.  Sou you can filter the datetime between today and tomorrow:

```
import datetime

today = datetime.date.today()
tomorrow = today + datetime.timedelta(days=1)

viewteam.daily_risk_set.filter(team=4713,
                               created__gte=today, created__lt=tomorrow) \
                       .order_by('-created')[:1]:
```